# Magento 2 filesystem permissions

Tags: magento2, security, permissions, filesystem

In Magento 2 we have a new filesystem permissions guidelines.

Reading [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) I understand that Magento requires php user inside `www-data` group.

What I do not understand is why `static` filesystem permissions are generated using `0770` instead of `0750`.

With this kind of permissions another user in the same server and belonging to `www-data` group will be able to modify all my files.

Isn't it dangerous? Is there any reason for this?

I know the Magento 2 approach is to always have a dedicated VM and I agree with it, but I do not see any good reason for this permissions settings.

Comment: We recommend 750 permissions in production mode, where you want security locked down. In development, when you're presumably inside a firewall with no outside access, it might not be necessary.

Comment: I've seen this is hardcoded in the Magento core, what I'm asking is the reason. I think there should be one.

Comment: Security. We have had multiple attacks where malicious code was written to a directory, either the root or pub. It's harder to carry out an attack if files aren't writeable or executable. Magento hard-codes permissions for both developer and production modes; AFAIK, default is the same as developer.

Comment: So why 770 instead of 750?

Comment: Depends on the [mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html) you're in.

Comment: OK, thank you. Il'check it deeper in my test install.